# Riverpod ref.watch(statenotifierprovider) vs ref.watch(statenotifierprovider.notifier)

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I've been trying to find out what is the difference between watching a `StateNotifierPovider` object vs watching the notifier exposed by it. As we can see in the docs following [section](https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#using-refread-to-obtain-the-state-of-a-provider) watching the notifier object does not trigger the object's build method when the state is changed. Out of experimenting, it seems like watching the provider object exposes the state within the notifier just as `ref.read(provider.notifier).state` would. I can't really get the difference between directly watching the provider vs `provider.notifier` and why it does not trigger the build method when watching the notifier and changing its state.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation of `.notifier` should hopefully be clear about it:

> Obtains the StateNotifier associated with this provider, without
> listening to state changes.
>
> This is typically used to invoke methods on a StateNotifier. For
> example:
>
> ```dart
> Button(
>  onTap: () => ref.read(stateNotifierProvider.notifer).increment(),
> )
> ```
>
> This listenable will notify its notifiers if the StateNotifier
> instance changes. This may happen if the provider is refreshed or one
> of its dependencies has changes.

https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AutoDisposeStateNotifierProvider/notifier.html

So `ref.watch(provider)` listens to state changes.

And `ref.watch(provider.notifier)` obtains the notifier only but does not listen to state change. Instead it listens to when the `StateNotifier` instance is recreated – such as if you did `ref.refresh(provider)`, which would recreate the `StateNotifier`

Comment: Awesome Remi! A few minutes ago I was digging the api docs and stumbled upon this documentation. Same about the refresh/invalidate methods (maybe this could be added to the v2 of the riverpod docs). Big fan of yours by the way, thanks for everything you've been doing for the flutter/dart community!

Comment: Im a simple man I see Remi I upvote.

Comment: Kindly explain when to use `ref.read(provider.notifier)` vs `ref.watch(provider.notifier)` inside callback functions(like onPressed) when not watching for state change but to modify state. Pl. take both cases of using them directly in functions compared to using their reference in functions, collected earlier in build method.

Comment: How can I watch the state chanes but getting the notifier instead?